# Is there a way to convert a VML document to a bitmap image?

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer, bitmap, vml

I've been looking for a long time for a way to have a bitmap from a VML document.
In fact, I working on a few libs that use the  tag, so I have no problem for anything except for IE (of course) because I'm using ExCanvas in IE, but I'd like to have a bitmap from the generated "canvas" (which is in fact VML).

I've been looking for a few ways to get a bitmap in JS from the VML, but I abandoned this idea, now I'd like to find a server side lib that is able to get a VML string and convert it to a bitmap image. My preferred language is PHP, but if there aren't any in this language, it'll be OK.
I also looked at a Java applet that could do that, but this is in fact impossible without a signed one, this is not possible.

Thank you for your reply !

Comment: Are you trying to capture a VML document after it has been rendered? In client side or server side?

Comment: I have the document client side, I know how to get it server side, that is not a problem.

Comment: No idea ? :(
It could maybe be done with an ActiveX, but ... it's would be an ActiveX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a library which looks like the best solution to my problem : [VectorConverter](http://vitali.web.cs.unibo.it/Progetti/VectorConverter).
It has however a few problems :

- it only supports a very limited part of the spec
- it is not maintained anymore
- the code is not very well written and it doesn't use an existing DOM parser for the VML
- I don't have time to enhance it !

So if anyone with a lot of time and who is interested in this project is welcome to work on it, and maybe fork it. Contact me if you plan to work on it, I may help you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/) to allow the browser to render it and capture that to an image.

Comment: Thank you for this tool, in fact I need the IE version (your page has a link to it : http://iecapt.sourceforge.net/). I didn't know it, but unfortunately, it requires an url to take a screenshot, I would like to take a screenshot of the current page, when I want to.

Answer (score 1):

The simple possibility is to use C# to display a window loading the vml page in ie webbrowser control and use  this.webBrowser.Navigate("file.html") to load the vml page included in the html
and then make a snap shot by capturing the image automatically by using graphic.CopyFromScreen function